# Count resolved critical and blocker issues sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I want to know how many critical and blocker have been resolved each day/month, but I didn't find how doing it!
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that I would be aware of to cover this use case.

Comment: Also with web service API ?

Comment: By playing with the "issues" web service you should be able to get what you want, see https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues. With "statuses=CLOSED", "s=CLOSE_DATE" and "severities=CRITICAL,BLOCKER"